# Tkinter entry widget in different Frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, tkinter-entry

I am starting to learn Python and the GUI, I am using the 3.7 version. My issue is with the entry widget.
I am just checking how the diferents widget are working with diferents frames and is not working like I thought it will work. So I want to do an app with two differents pages or more but I starting with two, and I want to change between them, every page will have differents widgets. In this case when I am using the call to the  Entry class in the second page or frame, the entry block is in the main page as well, so I just want the entry block in one page or frame.  As you can see I using .pack() with entry I would like to use .grid() but python show me an error when I tried to do it.

Thank you for your help.

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class mainapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # self.geometry("800x600")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, NewData):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background='white')
        labeltop = tk.Label(self, text="Hello\n"
                                       "Please Select a option:",
                            bg="white", fg="green", height=4, width=30, font=LARGE_FONT)
        labeltop.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, columnspan=2)

        self.logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
        logolabel=tk.Label(self, image=self.logo)
        logolabel.grid(row=0, column=3)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Option1", fg="White", bg="Green", height=6, width=30,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewData))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=10)


class NewData(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background='white')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Option1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        E1 = tk.Entry()
        E1.pack()

        button1.grid()

app = mainapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create widgets, you must tell them where they belong. When you do `tk.Entry()` you aren't doing that so it defaults to going into the root window.

If you want the entry to be inside a specific page, you need to give that page or one of its children as the master for the entry: `tk.Entry(self)`.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I can't test it at the moment, but you can't use pack *and* grid in one layout. I would tend to use grid in your case.

Comment: be careful with your wording. Your use of "layout" is ambiguous here. You can't use grid and pack together with widgets that have the same master, but you _can_ use them together to create a layout composed of many nested widgets.